How to add link in Slider image using page builder in magento 2 cloud edition
The Slider images were created using page builder and it displayed properly.
How to add a redirect url, when clicking the slider image (when clicking the slider image, that url should be redirected to the new page like category, etc..).
Anyone please help.
Thanks,
